# hours is not valid member of Folder "Players.trynotazies.leaderstats"

Tags: roblox

For some reason when I am trying to save the data for my leader stats script it says not a valid member. Any help would be appreciated right now. This is for a game I am making on Roblox and hoping for it to grow popular

Here is the code:

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local DataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("DataStore")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player

    local hours = Instance.new("IntValue")
    hours.Name = "Hours"
    hours.Value = 0
    hours.Parent = leaderstats

    local Sleep_Tokens = Instance.new("IntValue")
    Sleep_Tokens.Name = "Sleep Tokens"
    Sleep_Tokens.Value = 0
    Sleep_Tokens.Parent = leaderstats

    local data
    local data2
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        data = DataStore:GetAsync(player.UserId.."-hours")
        data2 = DataStore:GetAsync(player.UserId.."-sleeptokens")
    end)

    if success then
        hours.Value = data
        Sleep_Tokens.Value = data2
    else
        print("Had an error while retrieving player data")
        warn(errormessage)
    end
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        DataStore:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-hours",player.leaderstats.hours.Value)
        DataStore:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-sleeptokens",player.leaderstats.Sleep_Tokens.Value)
    end)

    if success then
        print("Player Data Saved")
    else
        print("Had an error while saving player data")
        warn(errormessage)
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that `hours` isn't a child of the player's leaderstats. This is because object names are case-sensitive, and when you created the IntValue, you named it `Hours` :

```
    local hours = Instance.new("IntValue")
    hours.Name = "Hours"
    hours.Value = 0
    hours.Parent = leaderstats
```

When you are saving the data, you either need to index the leaderstats using the proper name `Hours` or change the IntValue's Name to be `hours`. You'll run into the same issue with `Sleep_Tokens`.

Try this :

```lua
        DataStore:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-hours", player.leaderstats.Hours.Value)
        DataStore:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-sleeptokens", player.leaderstats["Sleep Tokens"].Value)
```